# Manage Google Drive files through App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm building a web application with app engine. In this app, users can submit texts about their tasks and upload/download (from/to their local machines) associated files.

I want to improve the upload/download feature using the Drive SDK. So, the users will be able to open and edit the submitted files through the app engine.

Someone knows what I have to do to integrate the two aproaches (app engine + drive sdk) and open/edit files through my web app?

Answer (score 4):

The Google Drive SDK documentation has complete sample applications and tutorials for both Java and Python applications running on App Engine that integrate with Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i would like to know if there is more practical samples like this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212508/java-drive-apiv2-appengine-1-7-3-struts2-3-4-1-oauth2-tokenresponseexceptio