# Python App Engine API to interact with Google Code Project Hosting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, integration, google-code

Referencing [Manage Google Drive files through App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523078/manage-google-drive-files-through-app-engine), I have kind of the same question about App Engine w.r.t. Google Code Project Hosting, i.e., is there a Python API to interact with the latter using the former.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to programatically upload files to a Google Code project, see the script at:

https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ScriptedUploads

What else were you looking to automate?